# Moving threads into another class Java

Tags: java, multithreading, class

I have a simple Java threads assignment that calculates average, max and min using threads. Currently, I have all my threads within one class. How can I move these threads into a separate "calculation class" then call the threads from the outside class within main? Below is my code and any help is appreciated!

```
import java.util.*;

public class Stats {
// Declaring the necessary variables.
static int x;
       static int[] input;
// Array of integers to hold the maximum and minimum values when computed in the
// thread. placeHolder[0] = min placeHolder[1] = max.
static int[] placeHolder = new int[2];
static double[] averageHolder = new double[1];

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Print statements prompting user/gathering input and storing into the array.
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many numbers would you like to compute?");
    x = scan.nextInt();
    input = new int[x];
    System.out.println("Please enter the numbers you would like computed:");
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        input[i] = scan.nextInt();
    }
    avgThread.start();
    minThread.start();
    maxThread.start();

    try {
        avgThread.join();
        minThread.join();
        maxThread.join();
    } catch (Exception i) {

    }

    System.out.printf("Avarage of Data : %f\nMinimum of Data : %d\nMaximum of Data :%d\n", averageHolder[0],
            placeHolder[0], placeHolder[1]);
}

static Thread maxThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int maximum = input[0];
        int i = 0;
        while (i < x) {
            if (maximum < input[i])
                maximum = input[i];
            i++;
        }
        placeHolder[1] = maximum;
    }
});

static Thread avgThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        double average = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < x) {
            average = average + input[i];
            i++;
        }
        average = average / x;
        averageHolder[0] = average;
    }
});

static Thread minThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int minimum = input[0];
        int i = 0;
        while (i < x) {
            if (minimum > input[i])
                minimum = input[i];
            i++;
        }

        placeHolder[0] = minimum;
    }
});
```

}

Comment: Creating threads and keeping references to them around isn't that different from any other data in classes and instances. You might want to think about making classes that implement `Runnable` and which keep their results internally and get the input array as a parameter. Try to build a reasonable structure first.

Comment: So what you're saying is create the threads. Then within main declare the thread like Thread maxThread = new Therad();?

Comment: Extract the relevant code from `Stats` to another class such as `StatsCalculator`.  Create a new instance of `StatsCalculator` in `main()` and call a `StatsCalculator` method that runs the threads.  Also, consider returning something like a `StatsResult` class instance to hold the results rather than a magic positional array.

Comment: Thank you Andrew. One last question. Since I'm doing the computations within the `StatsCalculator` now, would I declare the variables inside that class then? Because how would the scanner link to the new class?

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

You asked:

> How can I move these threads into a separate "calculation class"

Define a class for each task, where each class implements the `Runnable` (or [`Callable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html)) interface.

```
class Avg implements Callable < Double > { … }
```

Your title asks:

> Moving threads into another class Java

Use an [executor service](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) to group and manage your threads.

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 3 );
Future < Double > futureAvg = executorService.submit( new Avg( … ) )
```

## Details

Avoid using `static` as it is not object-oriented.

In modern Java, we rarely address [`Thread`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html) directly. Instead, we use the *Executors* framework. See [tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html). An [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) abstracts away dealing with threads.

When you want your background task to return a value, use [`Callable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) rather than [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runnable.html). When we submit each `Callable` (average, min, max) to our executor service, we get back a `Future` that will eventually hold our result.

After submitting all our `Callable` tasks, we ask the executor service to shut down after the tasks are completed (or canceled, or failed). We wait a while for that shutdown to complete. Then we interrogate each `Future` object for its result.

We gather our results (average, minimum, maximum) into an object of a custom class of our own design to hold those three values, to communicate data transparently and immutably. In Java 16+, the [records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) feature makes writing such a class utterly simple: Just declare the type and name of each member field. The compiler implicitly writes the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`.

Rather than having one long `main` method, break it up into purpose-driven chunks. Here we have three parts: gather inputs, process those inputs to produce results, and finally report those results.

Notice how we change the implementation of any of those three parts without affecting the others, as long as we abide by the contract of sharing an `int[]` array and a `Results` object. This [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) helps to make your software robust, easier to maintain and evolve, and more understandable.

Java has two type systems: primitives and classes (objects). `Double` is a class wrapping a primitive `double` value. Ditto for `Integer`/`int`. Java can usually auto-convert between these in a process known as [auto-boxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

And `Double`/`double` is the [64-bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing) floating-point type equivalent, for larger/smaller numbers than the [32-bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/32-bit) `Float`/`float` [floating-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) type.

```java
package work.basil.threads;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.OptionalDouble;
import java.util.OptionalInt;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Computation
{
    record Results( Double average , Integer min , Integer max ) { }

    private int[] gatherInputs ()
    {
        // …
        return new int[] { 7 , 42 , 99 };
    }

    private Results compute ( int[] inputs )
    {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 3 );

        Future < Double > futureAvg = executorService.submit( new Avg( Arrays.copyOf( inputs , inputs.length ) ) );
        Future < Integer > futureMin = executorService.submit( new Min( Arrays.copyOf( inputs , inputs.length ) ) );
        Future < Integer > futureMax = executorService.submit( new Max( Arrays.copyOf( inputs , inputs.length ) ) );

        executorService.shutdown();
        try { executorService.awaitTermination( 1 , TimeUnit.MINUTES ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        Results results = null;
        try { results = new Results( futureAvg.get() , futureMin.get() , futureMax.get() ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); } catch ( ExecutionException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        return Objects.requireNonNull( results );
    }

    private void reportResults ( Results results )
    {
        System.out.println( "results = " + results );
    }


    class Avg implements Callable < Double >
    {
        private int[] inputs;

        public Avg ( int[] inputs )  // Constructor
        {
            Objects.requireNonNull( inputs );
            if ( inputs.length == 0 ) { throw new IllegalArgumentException( "The inputs int[] must not be empty." ); }
            this.inputs = inputs;
        }

        @Override
        public Double call () throws Exception
        {
            OptionalDouble optionalDouble = Arrays.stream( inputs ).average();
            return optionalDouble.orElseThrow(); // Should never throw as we verified in constructor that the inputs were not empty.
        }
    }

    class Min implements Callable < Integer >
    {
        private int[] inputs;

        public Min ( int[] inputs )  // Constructor
        {
            Objects.requireNonNull( inputs );
            if ( inputs.length == 0 ) { throw new IllegalArgumentException( "The inputs int[] must not be empty." ); }
            this.inputs = inputs;
        }

        @Override
        public Integer call () throws Exception
        {
            OptionalInt optionalInt = Arrays.stream( inputs ).min();
            return optionalInt.orElseThrow(); // Should never throw as we verified in constructor that the inputs were not empty.
        }
    }

    class Max implements Callable < Integer >
    {
        private int[] inputs;

        public Max ( int[] inputs )  // Constructor
        {
            Objects.requireNonNull( inputs );
            if ( inputs.length == 0 ) { throw new IllegalArgumentException( "The inputs int[] must not be empty." ); }
            this.inputs = inputs;
        }

        @Override
        public Integer call () throws Exception
        {
            OptionalInt optionalInt = Arrays.stream( inputs ).max();
            return optionalInt.orElseThrow(); // Should never throw as we verified in constructor that the inputs were not empty.
        }
    }


    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        Computation app = new Computation();
        int[] inputs = app.gatherInputs();
        Results results = app.compute( inputs );
        app.reportResults( results );
    }

}
```

When run.

> results = Results[average=49.333333333333336, min=7, max=99]

I should note that your particular case here is not an appropriate use of multi-threading. Concurrency is not magic, and comes with a cost, an ["overhead"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overhead_(computing)). Calculating average, min, and max on a small number of `int` values is not likely to justify that overhead. But I assume this is just practice for learning about concurrency. For that purpose, this is a worthwhile exercise.